# Predicate in set builder notation explicitly describing the combinations of a set

Tags: combinatorics, notation

I'm confident the set of permutations of a set $A$ (with elements taken 2 at a time, as a simplified example) can generally be described as
$$\{(a_{i_1},a_{i_2}):a_{i_1},a_{i_2}\in A\wedge i_1,i_2\in [1,|A|]\wedge i_1\neq i_2\}$$

or in the case where all elements in $A$ are unique:
$$\{(a,b):a,b\in A\wedge a\neq b\}$$
.
In regard to describing combinations of a set in a similar manner I fear a reader may overlook the fact that a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) "$\{\}$" is unordered with no repeated elements in contrast with a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) "$()$" in both respects (i.e. a tuple is ordered and allows for duplicate elements). So that the definition of combinations of $A$ taken 2 at a time
$$
\{\{a_{i_1},a_{i_2}\}:a_{i_1},a_{i_2}\in A\wedge i_1,i_2\in [1,|A|]\wedge i_1\neq i_2\}
$$
may not be explicit enough to distinguish it from that of permutations. As a consequence of this with both prior definitions in mind the combinations of $A=\{1,2\}$ taken 2 at a time like its permutations $\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ may be (mis)understood to be $\{\{1,2\},\{2,1\}\}$ instead of self-impliying $\{1,2\}$ since a set by definition has no repeated elements and is unordered. Is it possible to define the combinations of a set using set-builder notation so that the distinction between tuple and set is more explicitly stated and "foolproof"?

Comment: To make matters worst my two definitions above are right only if $A$ is a vector and not a set since another property of a set is that it can't be indexable by virtue of it being unordered.

Comment: How about $\{C\subseteq A:|C|=2\}$?

Comment: Also, instead of trying to directly define permutations/combinations of an indexed collection that can contain duplicates, consider using permutations/combinations of the index set.